# do I need lock to protect python 2.7 list in multi-threaded environment?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Wondering if we need lock on a Python list if multiple threads needs to access (read/write/get size)? Using Python 2.7 on Mac.

I have written a prototype to add a lock to protect the list. Not sure if necessary or any issues (for both performance and functional) in my code? Thanks.

BTW, I have the same question on Python dictionary and deque, about whether we need lock to protect it in a multi-threaded environment. Thanks.

```
import threading
import time
import random

class checkStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = []
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
    def checkInStatus(self, msg):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.message.append(msg)
        self.lock.release()
    def checkOutStatus(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        if len(self.message) > 0:
            msg = self.message.pop(0)
        else:
            msg = 'Queue empty'
        self.lock.release()
        return msg
    def checkMessageStatus(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        size = len(self.message)
        self.lock.release()
        return size

messageQueue = checkStatus()

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        global messageQueue
        while True:
            time.sleep(1+5*random.random())
            print "%s: %s : %s" % (self.name, time.ctime(time.time()), messageQueue.checkMessageStatus())
            time.sleep(1 + 5 * random.random())
            msg = time.ctime(time.time()) + ' ' + self.name
            print "%s: %s : check in message, %s" % (self.name, time.ctime(time.time()), msg)
            messageQueue.checkInStatus(msg)
            time.sleep(1 + 5 * random.random())
            print "%s: %s : check out message, %s" % (self.name, time.ctime(time.time()), messageQueue.checkOutStatus())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []

    # Create new threads
    thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1")
    thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2")

    # Start new Threads
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    # Add threads to thread list
    threads.append(thread1)
    threads.append(thread2)

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Output,

```
Thread-2: Tue Aug 30 22:08:04 2016 : 0
Thread-1: Tue Aug 30 22:08:05 2016 : 0
Thread-1: Tue Aug 30 22:08:07 2016 : check in message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:07 2016 Thread-1
Thread-2: Tue Aug 30 22:08:07 2016 : check in message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:07 2016 Thread-2
Thread-2: Tue Aug 30 22:08:09 2016 : check out message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:07 2016 Thread-1
Thread-1: Tue Aug 30 22:08:11 2016 : check out message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:07 2016 Thread-2
Thread-2: Tue Aug 30 22:08:11 2016 : 0
Thread-1: Tue Aug 30 22:08:13 2016 : 0
Thread-2: Tue Aug 30 22:08:15 2016 : check in message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:15 2016 Thread-2
Thread-1: Tue Aug 30 22:08:17 2016 : check in message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:17 2016 Thread-1
Thread-2: Tue Aug 30 22:08:18 2016 : check out message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:15 2016 Thread-2
Thread-1: Tue Aug 30 22:08:19 2016 : check out message, Tue Aug 30 22:08:17 2016 Thread-1
```

Comment: In multithreading, the CPython implementation has a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), so that only one thread is active at a time. So, you do not need a lock.

Comment: Thread stop internally (best safe way), need create `pause`,`stop`,`lock` condition for every thread. Additional status is `Failed`  and `while True :` is nightmare for threading. Data and data ways will be corrupted if not handle flags. You got some data or processes in thread but `synchronous and internal data bindings` excepted a lot combination if an `error` occurred.

Comment: @super_cr7, is there a way to change the default behavior?

Comment: @dsgdfg, what do you mean "Thread stop internally"? In my example specifically, what does it mean?

Comment: @super_cr7, also wondering if there is another Python interpreter which I can use to test true multi-threaded behavior, besides CPython implementation?

Comment: @LinMa From [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock): `Jython` and `IronPython` have no GIL and can fully exploit multiprocessor systems.

Comment: @super_cr7, thanks a lot and will try. Just curious, CPython seems most popular, but it does not support multi-threading, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkOutStatus` method requires a lock to work properly; the other methods do not since they are performing atomic operations (simple Python statement are atomic, see this [reference](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm)).  Without a lock in checkOutStatus, there can be a case where the if statement evaluates to True but a thread switch occurs immediately, before retrieving the message with `self.message.pop(0)`.  If the second thread then removes the message, when the first thread continues it will attempt to pop from an empty list.  If you rewrite the function as follows:

```
def checkOutStatus(self):
    try:
        msg = self.message.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        msg = 'Queue empty'
    return msg
```

it too will be threadsafe, since the only operation is atomic.  In that case you could drop all the locking code.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I already add `self.lock.acquire()` and `self.lock.release()` in `checkOutStatus`, you mean my specific implementation has issues?

Comment: No real issues.  Your implementation will work, but if you remove the lock it will occasionally fail.  Your other methods don't need a lock at all.  My example would also let you remove the lock from `checkOutStatus`.  In general the `try:except:` construction is preferred to the if statement approach, and this is one of the reasons why.

Comment: Sure, thanks Paul. But my confusion is, I think we need a lock for pop method, why you do not add a lock in your `checkOutStatus `? Did I mis-read any of your comments?

Comment: The pop method is atomic.  A task switch cannot occur *during* the execution of the pop statement, so no lock is necessary.  But imagine what can happen when you use an `if` statement instead: Thread1 calls checkOutStatus and there's one item in `message`.  So the `if` is true.  Suppose a task switch to Thread2 at that instant.  Thread2 happens also to call checkOutStatus; the `if` is *still* true because Thread1 hasn't done `pop` yet.  Thread2 calls `pop`.  But now when Thread1 resumes, `message` is empty so `pop` throws an exception.   That's the difference.

Comment: Hi Paul, I studied the reference blog and it really informative. Vote up! I re-think my problem, I still think I should add lock to method `checkMessageStatus`, since even if `len` is atomic, but it is possible another thread is adding/removing elements in the same list, how do you think?

Comment: Again, you should add a lock to *your* implementation of `checkMessageStatus` because the two-step removal of an item *isn't atomic*; *my* implementation of `checkMessageStatus` uses a one-step removal, which *is atomic*, and therefore it doesn't need a lock.  You can add one to my implementation if you want, but it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks Paul, vote up. What do you mean `two-step removal`? I think `checkMessageStatus ` just check length, why you mention `removal` here?

Comment: I mention removal because checkMessageStatus removes (pops) an item from the list.  There are two steps in your version: you check to see if len() > 0 (step one) and then remove (pop) an item if it is (step two).  As I have tried to explain, a task switch can occur after step one and before step two, in which case it's possible that a second thread has removed the last item.  Then the pop method will raise an exception.  To prevent this you need a lock.  My implementation just does the pop method (one step), and if it fails the except block runs.  One step = no lock needed.

Comment: Thanks Paul, vote up. I think you mean `checkOutStatus ` check length then try to remove, which is two steps, correct? The method `checkMessageStatus ` only checks length, I think no lock is needed. Did I mis-read anything?

Comment: Hi Paul, if you could response to my above question, it will be great, thanks.:)

Comment: Checking length = one step.  The next statement, after the "if", is a second step.  If something in the second step changes the result of the "if" statement (such as removing the last item), then the code isn't threadsafe.  This is a generic aspect of multithreaded programming and isn't specific to Python.  A person experienced in multithreaded programming will recognize at once that such a construction is dangerous, although it may take many hours of runtime before it shows up as a bug.  Python has the nice feature that a single line of code is atomic, which isn't true in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I think you are talking about `checkOutStatus`, correct? But you can find you were referring to `checkMessageStatus`, which is the whole confusion here. :)

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the confirm Paul, mark your reply as answer.